# Delphi - Text is printed out on black background

Tags: delphi, printing, background, transparency

I print out text on the printer canvas using `Printer.Canvas.TextOut()`.

I have several printer jobs defined - some for graphics and some for plain text. This has worked fine until now. Now I have a problem that plain text prints out on a black background.

This happens only if I do a graphical print before a text print (it doesn't matter whether the same printer is used or not).

I have no idea what is causing this problem. I don't set a black background anywhere. So I hope that you can help.

The problem appears with PCL & Postscript.

In the print preview of my PCL-printer, everything looks fine. However, the final print on paper is black on black again.

Could there be a transparency flag causing this problem?

---

*Edit*: It seems the transparency was causing the problem. If I use:

```
SetBkMode( Printer.Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT );
```

before printing the plain text, everything works fine now.  It seems I messed up something somewhere.

Comment: Is this only on one specific machine + printer or more than one? Btw, if you think you've found a solution, it would be helpful to future readers if you post it as an answer (answering your own q is fine  on SO).  That way, it will show up as an answered q rather than an unanswered one, at the risk of stating the obvious.

Comment: Not sure yet whether this is the solution or only the workaround for the problem. This is neither a computer nor a printer specific problem. I also believe that the PCL preview of my printer (Kyocera) is bugged - it shouldn't have previewed it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the BkMode to transparent solved the problem - but it was only a workaround.

The reason for the problem was that in the graphic print, `Printer.Canvas.Brush.Color` was being set to `clBlack` when drawing solid circles. And this value was not being reset correctly.